# MySql : Select statement inside Check statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have to create a table as following

Borrower(customerNo,LoanNo)

customers can take loans if they havent take more than 3 loans.

I created table as follows

```
create table borrower(
customerno int(5),
LoanNo int(5),
primary key(customerno,loanno),
check( customerno not in 
(select customerno from borrower group by customerno having count(loanno)>=4))
);
```

But it givs me an error saying

```
[root@localhost:3306] ERROR 1146: Table 'test.borrower' doesn't exist
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error??

Comment: your borrower table has no column named customerno and loanno,only it has customerid and loanid

Comment: Lets say i change customerno into customerid and loanno to loanid but still the main problem exists.

Comment: you can't add a check on a table that does not exists. because it is the same table. it is just a paradox you tried to use. You can't get the egg of a chicken that you will breed from that egg :o)

Comment: I got the point. Is there any solution for it?
i need to add this constraint to it
customers can take loans if they havent take more than 3 loans.

Comment: seems u would like to put the complete business rules into the table structure ... don't do this ... this belongs to the validation part of your application, not storage

Comment: You mean like creating a trigger??

Comment: No, this can be done with a stored procedure u will use to fill the data instead of a direct table access. u can provide a result code if it was successful or not

Comment: Thank you very much SirRufo.You made it clear.

Comment: mysql accepts check constraints but doesn't parse them. In other words they are useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's giving the error is because the `CHECK` constraint refers to the table being created, but it doesn't exist at the time that the statement is parsed.

But I have some bad news for you... **mysql ignores `CHECK` constraints**. It is allowed as syntax only for compatibility with create statements from other databases.

See the [mysql documentation for CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You'll have to use a trigger, but note that you can't throw an exception from one. The best you can hope for is when you detect a problem, do something like execute `SELECT * FROM TOO_MANY_LOANS` and hope that the caller figures out what the error "No such table TOO_MANY_LOANS" really means.

Answer (score 2):

As this belongs to the business rules and not to data structure you should use a Stored Procedure like this

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddCustomerLoan`(IN Acustomerno int(5), IN ALoanNo int(5), OUT ResultCode INT)
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO @LoanCount
FROM borrower
WHERE customerno = Acustomerno;

IF @LoanCount < 4 THEN

    INSERT INTO borrower ( customerno, LoanNo )
    VALUES ( Acustomerno, ALoanNo );

    SET ResultCode = 0;

ELSE

    -- Too many Entries
    SET ResultCode = 1;

END IF;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The ResultCode will inform your application if it was successful or not, and why not successful.

Another advantage is that you can modify the maximum entries or get the maximum entries per customer, without changing your application code.

Comment: should he use a stored proc, should he?

Comment: @RumeshEranga you are welcome - but you can also up vote for useful answers, and accept that answer, that answers your question